# Radiation of a circular orbit intensity and polarisation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics

> Consider a (non-relativistic) particle with charge q on a circular orbit with radius $r$ and angular velocity $\omega$.

I would now like to calculate and draw the radiation profile due to the dipole moments and find the polarization of the radiation.

> $$\vec{p}(t)=qRe^{-i \omega t} ê_{\perp}$$ and $$\vec{m}(t)= \frac{qw}{2}R^2 ê_z$$ where a vector with a hat denotes the unit vector in this direction.

As a start, I have calculated the electric and magnetic dipole moments (as given above) but now got stuck. I think I have to find the Poynting vector. This however requires the vector potential of this configuration (to find the E- and B- fields). I have no idea on the polarization part of my question. Qualitatively, I think the radiation should be circular on the z-axis and planar in the xy-plane. 
How would you go on to calculate these quantities?

Comment: Please read carefully [our guidelines for homework and exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714). I should also note that your question appears to be incomplete.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - I don't think this violates the homework policy - but it's definitely incomplete in its current state. Quasar: you might want to look at [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation#Polarization_of_synchrotron_radiation)

Comment: If this isn't homework (*i.e.* you're not on a time limit and you're just interested), you might think about using the [Liénard-Weichert potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liénard–Wiechert_potential) for this problem and the field vectors derived from them. It's a great deal easier than slogging away from first principles. I set up a Mathematica notebook along these lines many years ago to explore the field vectors and the use of field plots once you've set an analysis up gives a great deal more intuition for the radiation than tangled equations.